# Bound event handlers no longer work after AJAX manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I am binding some jQuery event handlers to an element in the page which work fine initially, however if the user selects a radio button on the page, that element gets removed; they can bring it back by selecting another radio button; however when the data is loaded back in by AJAX the function no longer fires from the event handler.

I am binding it with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#buyout_field').mouseleave(function() {
        update();
    });    

    jQuery('#buyout_field').focusout(function() {
        update();
    });

});
```

So to recap, runs fine initially, but once AJAX removes and then puts the data back it no longer runs.

Here is the the code that runs the AJAX:

```
function update() {

    getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'GET', 'json')

        .done(function(response) {

            // Add/Hide other data
            jQuery('#buy_now').html(response.buy_now);            

        })

    // End

}

function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: action,
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: type
    });    

}
```

The element `buyout_field` is contained within the `buy_now` element.

Isn't the element put back into the DOM or something?

Comment: show us ur HTML structure

Comment: add some of your html so we can see the scope of your bindings. replacing html of course destroys the elements inside and any of handlers assignd to them. If you put some html in here, we can help you to deal with it using "live" or "delegate" event handlers

Comment: @Luke or better .on() as live() is removed as for jq 1.9

Comment: @Luke Both of which are deprecated for `on`.

Comment: @roasted it is? wow... did nt know. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#buy_now').on('mouseleave', '#buyout_field', function() {
    update();
});

jQuery('#buy_now').on('focusout', '#buyout_field', function() {
    update();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **delegate the events...**

```
 jQuery(document).on('focus', '#buyout_field', function() {
     update();
 });

 jQuery('#buyout_field').on({
   mouseleave : function() {
       update();
   }, $(document)
 });
```

It is always a better idea to replace the events delegated to the document , to a static ancestor to which the events are bound.. In this case `'#buy_now'` will be the static parent as it is always present on the page when the event is bound.